# python not detecting changes if importing from root

Tags: python

For some reason, my changes aren't reflected if I import a class relative to the root. Here's an example:

```
  root/__init__.py
       subdir/__init__.py
              bar.py
```

If I cd to subdir and do:

```
>>> from bar import baz
>>> dir(baz)
```

This reflects my changes and shows the method I added to baz

However, if I do:

```
>>> from subdir.bar import baz
>>> dir(baz)
```

This does NOT reflect my changes

I've deleted all .pyc files in this project. This is driving me nuts!!

Comment: Have you checked your permissions on the directory?

Comment: Have you checked your PYTHONPATH? Maybe there is somewhere an old version hanging around...

Comment: I have drwxrwxr-x on subdir and -rw-rw-r-- on bar

Comment: AHHHH Andreas that was it! It was pointing to another copy! Thanks so much. Can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Andreas said in the comments fixed it:

"Have you checked your PYTHONPATH? Maybe there is somewhere an old version hanging around..."